# Lost ETH, can't work out what wallet was used to store it

Tags: ether, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets, myetherwallet

I bought some Ethereum on behalf of my parents in 2017. I *think* we decided to store the currency on my Ledger Live but on a different address. I have the password for every wallet I've ever created by the problem is I can't work out what account is holding the ETH/ where it is stored. Can anyone help?

The Wallet address for the Eth is: 0xaf60cff21be10fbc08f64ea524640afaec62da4e

I think it's located on my Ledger Live but it could be in Jaxx or have been created using MyEtherWallet- I can't remember....

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you try using the ledget with those wallets?